# Firebase: Store server timestamp when document created

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I use this code :

```
firestore().collection("item").add({...item, created: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP})
```

It creates entry `{".sv" : "timestamp"}` <-- actual word "timestamp"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a document in Firestore, but trying to get a timestamp from the Realtime Database, which is a different Firebase Product.

**Here's how to use Firestore's timestamp** (Updated on Feb 2019):

```
firestore().collection("item")
 .add({...item, created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) })
```

Comment: What must you put into pubspec.yaml to import this?

Comment: @Tyler I assume you're using Flutter. Adding the [`cloud_firestore`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore) plugin should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I have this at the top: 
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

But still getting the error:
Error: The getter 'firebase' isn't defined ...

Comment: This sounds like a different problem. Please [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=firebase+flutter+google-cloud-firestore)

Answer (score 16):

At the time of writing this, the accepted solution does not work. The expression `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is no longer valid. The `Timestamp` is now direcly inside `firestore`.

Thus, to get the current server time in seconds you can write

```
require('firebase-admin').firestore.Timestamp.now()._seconds
```

Comment: Actually, your answer refers to the NodeJS Admin SDK. The accepted answer uses the Javascript Client-side SDK

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes , thanks. But using Timestamp from FieldValue is what Google suggests for NodeJs in their firestore help here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data    which no longer works.

Comment: Currently I have to make a Cloud Function as you said to request server time to client, then use that time to write from client back to server.

Comment: I think this simply creates a timestamp based on your computer's time, not based on what time Firebase server thinks it is.

Comment: @BorisYakubchik did you get the solution for this, the solution shown here take device time

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me (on March 2020):

```
Firestore.instance.collection("item").add({...other items, 'created': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

The result in Cloud Firestore is:

[Cloud Firestore Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqKxu.png)

Answer (score 1):

I use the official suggestion as here below:

```
updateDoc(doc.ref, {
timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```