# Can't add curent time into firebase firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use current time to input in firebase firestore (timestamp). When I use the following code:

```
today: number = Date.now();
```

everything works fine, but time is updated only once (when a page is downloaded). So I did time update:

```
updatedTime(): void {
  setInterval(() => {
  this.today = new Date();
}, 1000);}
```

and then

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.updatedTime();
}
```

That works when I display time in the browser, but it doesn't work when I input `_today` into firebase firestore.

How to fix that?

Also there's a reason to use Date or better use timestamp that's provided by firebase apis?

Comment: Firebase does provide a way to store timestamp in Firestore. Have a look at [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969509/5861618)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question fully, but I use the built-in function `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to set the current timestamp whilst adding and updating.

Here is an example snippet...

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const firestore = require('firebase/firestore');

// ...

let docRef = await this.db.collection('accounts').doc(accountId);
docRef.update({
  name,
  lastModified: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a timestamp object in Firestore, you need to provide a Date object in the document you want to create or update, such as `new Date()`.  Don't use a number value, such as the value returned by `Date.now()`, otherwise you will just see that number.  This is true for each language binding with Firestore - they must each use their native Date type.