# Firestore cloud functions error: Invalid use of type "function" as a Firestore argument.

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone assist with this error please? I have seen the similar answer to "Firebase firestore cloud functions showing Error: Invalid use of type “undefined” as a Firestore argument", but that answer does not help.

```
Error: Invalid use of type "function" as a Firestore argument.
    at Object.customObjectError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:168:16)
    at Serializer.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:146:26)
    at Serializer.encodeFields (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:54:34)
    at Serializer.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:139:44)
    at Serializer.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:124:38)
    at Serializer.encodeFields (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:54:34)
    at Function.fromObject (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/document.js:77:53)
    at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:245:54)
    at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:349:27)
    at exports.userSignupData.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/user_code/lib/userSignupData.js:9:20
```

The function is used in an ionic 4 app:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const userSignupData = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
  const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

  return userRef.set({
    id: user.uid,
    createdAt: context.timestamp,
    signupEmail: user.email,
    emailVerified: user.email,
    originalSigninProvider: user.providerData
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems firebase does not like a duplicate property call in the set object i.e.

```
signupEmail: user.email,
emailVerified: user.email,
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data you are trying to upload, `context.timestamp` is probably of type function, meaning you are trying to push a function rather than a valid 'date' or 'timestamp' to firestore.

As per [this thread on creating timestamps in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967868/firebase-store-server-timestamp-when-document-created), you can pass a valid timestamp as of **Feb 2019**, as such:

```
firestore().collection("item")
.add({...item, created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) })
```