# Firestore database - document creations date time in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a firestore database document creations date time while in Android.

I know that there is a class called FieldValue with method serverTimestamp() available to write up the server date and time in document, but that works only at document update and not while creating a document.

Can anyone suggest how can I add server date time while creating documents.

Thanks

Comment: Can this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969509/14759470

Comment: As I have created the custom model class in Android, I need to give a try whether that solution works or not in Android.

Comment: Give it a go and let me know

Comment: You should use @ServerTimestamp and leave the property uninitialized.

Comment: @alex mano, hmm I made mistake then along with ServerTimestamp, I have assigned value to that property just before adding document. I will check n get back with outcome.