# Firebase. How can I listen to a collection and get the ID of the latest modified doc in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, optimization, google-cloud-firestore, listener

We need to figure out how to check a firebase collection for changes and then get the ID of the document that was just added or deleted.

**What we have done so far.**

Currently, we get the details of the added and deleted documents by using the following Node JS code.  `db.collection('collection').onSnapshot.then(snap => {let changedDocs = snap._changes()}`.

The issue with this approach is that using`snap._changes()` is very costly and ends up using up a lot of our project's read queries. Is there some other alternative solution to our goals that we're missing?

Comment: Do you mean `db.collection('collection').get(...` ?  The pithy answer is to add a timestamp on creation and query the collection, ordering by that date.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967868/firebase-store-server-timestamp-when-document-created

Answer (score 0):

The requirements you have of finding the document that was "just added or deleted" are a bit vague.  You'll have to firm up your problem description in terms of the capabilities that Firestore actually has for queries and listeners.

Firestore doesn't maintain any information about *when* a document was added, removed, or deleted.  These operations just happen.  Even if you have a listener that would trigger on one of these changes, you can't be assured that your callback will be invoked immediately on that change (because your app could be offline at the time of the change, or experience some latency, receiving the callback some time later).

What you can do is know the latest add or update if you add a field that contains the a timestamp of that change.  You can certainly order your query by that timestamp, limit to the first one, and receive just that document.  But you would potentially miss out on other changes that happened around the same time that your listener will miss.

Also, you will miss documents that were deleted.  Deleted documents don't show up in any query.  You would instead have to mark the document as deleted by changing a field, and using that in your query.

Without knowing more about your actual requirements, it's really hard to say if Firestore is a good tool for this job.  You'll have to map your requirements into queries that Firestore actually supports, and be aware of how you might be missing data, given how listener work.  Maybe you are better off using a pub/sub queue to process changes as a stream so that you don't miss anything.