`serverTimestamp()` is not being updated correctly while other data is written properly when the user is not logged in
When the user wants to connect with an expert, they submit data in the below format.
SearchTalent.js component
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const loginState = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
  let uploads = await uploadSelectedFiles();
  const saveData = {
    // taskName: taskName,
    description: description,
    loomLink: loomLink,
    uploadFiles: uploads,
    expertCategories: expertCategories,
    post_userid: currentUserUid,
    posterRole: myRole,
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
  };
  if (loginState == "true") {
    setLoader(true);
    let newJobId = await writeJobPostToDb(saveData);
    console.log(newJobId, "this is a hilarious jobid");
    // Get the updated document from Firestore to access the actual timestamp
    sendNewJobNotify(newJobId, skillSet, expertCategories);
    navigate(`/Portfolio/id=${currentUserUid}/order-history`);
    localStorage.removeItem("jobPostData");
  } else {
    // localStorage.setItem("taskName", JSON.stringify(taskName));
    localStorage.setItem(
      "expertCategories",
      JSON.stringify(expertCategories)
    );
    //navigate(`/Portfolio/id=${currentUserUid}/order-history`);
    localStorage.setItem("jobPostData", JSON.stringify(saveData));
    navigate("./register");
  }
};

common.js utils
export const writeJobPostToDb = async (data) => {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "jobpost"), data);
  return docRef.id;
};

Customers post their requirements to find out the experts and those data are stored on the Firestore. It works as normal when the user logged in, but it doesn't log the timestamps correctly when the user is not logged in.
In normal, it should be like this.
timestamp
September 2, 2024 at 10:19:56 AM UTC-7

But seeing this on the jobpost data that created before the user Signup to the platform.
timestamp     (map)
_methodName: "serverTimestamp" (string)

The whole jobpost collection field looks like this.
description: "" (string)

expertCategories: (array)
0 "Nuke" (string)

loomLink: "" (string)

post_userid: "v7mCJl07XLO3kQL6AWC7" (string)

posterRole: ""(string)

timestamp:  (map)
    _methodName: "serverTimestamp" (string)

uploadFiles

Other fields are fine, but only the timestamp not working.
I've checked the Firestore rule setup, and asyc/await till the DB update and I was able to reproduce this by triggering the handleSubmit without Login/Signup to the platform.
First time visiters of the website can also create the jobpost by triggering handleSubmit, and they will be redirecting to the register page first. Temporary jobpost data created by the user before Signup, first stored on the localStorage.
I changed above code to this and solve the issue temporarily.
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const loginState = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");

  if (loginState == "true") {
    let uploads = await uploadSelectedFiles();
    const saveData = {
      description: description,
      loomLink: loomLink,
      uploadFiles: uploads,
      expertCategories: expertCategories,
      post_userid: currentUserUid,
      posterRole: myRole,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    };

    setLoader(true);
    let newJobId = await writeJobPostToDb(saveData);
    sendNewJobNotify(newJobId, skillSet, expertCategories);

    navigate(`/Portfolio/id=${currentUserUid}/order-history`);
    localStorage.removeItem("jobPostData");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(
      "expertCategories",
      JSON.stringify(expertCategories)
    );
    navigate("./register");
  }
};

App.js
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout onlogin={isLoggedIn} />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
           <Route path="/order-instant" element={<SearchTalent />} />

Home.js component
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full p-0 sm:p-6 px-auto">
        <SearchTalent />

I am using the Firebase SDK version ^9.23.0
Has anyone else encountered this issue? I really hop for some assistance on this!

What do you mean by "sometimes it doesn't log the timestamps correctly"?  Are you saying that it works as expected in some cases but not in other cases?  Can you edit the question be clear about a specific case where it doesn't ever work as expected, and compare that to one where it always works?  Without a way to reliably reproduce the problem, you're not likely to get much help.

Hi @DougStevenson. Yes, so the platform is designed to match client with experts. Clients can post their Job post on this platform. The thing is that already registered users can sign in to the platform and create jobpost, then there is no such an issue, but when they first visit our platform, they are not registered and not logged in at all. They can hit the button called Connect with an expert and this leads them to the register page. But the basic data of job post are stored in localstorage. If the user finishes the signup, then jobpost data is saved on the Firestore.

That doesn't really answer my questions.  Could you please read my comment again and update your question with the details I asked for, focusing on the code and steps that reliably doesn't work the way you expect (not "sometimes").

Yes. normally, timestamp: serverTimestamp(), this works fine. But in certain edge case, I don't get timestamps on the Firestore. Instead, I only see timestamp     (map) _methodName: "serverTimestamp" (string) for timestamp field. I was able reproduce this edge case. Triggering handleSubmit before the user login to the platform, was the source of this issue. That's related to the Firestore rule I've set, I think.

Please edit the question to explain how to reproduce the specific edge case.  It should not be a "sometimes" problem - it needs to be reliable.  Use the edit link at the bottom of the question.  Don't leave more information as comments on the question as you have been doing.  We should be able to follow the instructions in the question to reproduce the problem.

You're still showing both "sometimes" cases.  Are you not able to construct a specific scenario make it work one way consistently?  Firestore doesn't have random behavior when it comes to server timestamps. We need to be able to reproduce this with regularity if you want our help.  You're almost certainly doing something wrong somewhere, but we can't see what it is.

Can you show us the code that you used to make the result "in normal" and compare that to the code that doesn't do the same thing? The difference between the two is probably what you're doing wrong.

You can instead use firebase.firestore.TimeStamp.now().toDate() to get a similar result.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp
end result will look like this 2024-09-25T06:50:47.426Z

I don't mean that modular serverTimestamp() function doesn't work, but I am curious in what case do I get above errors. All other fields are written correctly on the Firestore, but only timestamps field didn't updated. How come this happens?

@AmericaDoodles When you call serverTimestamp() the timestamp is generated server side so I think the fact it's not working has something do with the server itself, sorry I couldn't find more info but I did find someone mentioning it is no longer working
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807235/15807478

Hi @HellBri8nger,
I discovered the issue. First-time visitors click the "Connect with an Expert" button and are then redirected to the "Signup" page since they're not authenticated. At this point, the jobpost collection is already created, but they don't have the necessary create permissions to update the document. Once they complete the signup and gain authentication, the serverTimestamp() doesn't work as expected. I was able to reproduce this bug myself. I think I've had a breakthrough on this issue!
